# improve 'check if true' function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that looks like this

```
$scope.object = {
  Title: 'A title',
  Status: 'Open',
  Responsible: 'John Doe',
  Author: 'Jane Doe',
  Description: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit'
}
```

Now I want to see if the current user has permission to edit this item, for the user to be able to edit, the item has to

- Exist (is not null, undefiend etc)
- Responsible is equal `$scope.currentUser`
- Status is equal 'Open'

if all these are true, our function should return true, I am doing it like this

```
$scope.isTrue = function(){

  if($scope.object && $scope.object.Status == 'Open' && $scope.object.Responsible == $scope.currentUser){
    return true;
  }else { return false; }

}
```

Pretty straight forward, but are there a better way to do these kind of checks?

Comment: You don't have to return `true/false`, you can just return everything in the if statement, this itself will already be true or false. so: `return $scope.object && $scope.object.Status == 'Open' && $scope.object.Responsible == $scope.currentUser`

Comment: @MartijnWelker that got a whole lot cleaner, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The condition in the if statement is already true or false, you can just return that.

```
return ($scope.object && $scope.object.Status == 'Open' && $scope.object.Responsible == $scope.currentUser);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Converting the result to Boolean (So, if `$scope.object` is `undefined` result is `false` instead of `undefined`)
2. [Making comparisons using `===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)
3. Just declaring function and assigning it to scope(personal preference)

---

```
$scope.isTrue = isTrue;

function isTrue() {
  return Boolean($scope.object && $scope.object.Status === 'Open' && $scope.object.Responsible === $scope.currentUser);
}
```